# Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type string and string

Tags: c#, variables, math, operator-keyword

I want to create a new variable using two string variables. But I keep getting the error message

> "operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type string and string c#".

```
string query3 = "SELECT Quantity FROM Supplier WHERE [Supplier ID]='"+supplierid+"'";
string query4 = "SELECT Quantity FROM Supplier WHERE [Book ID] = '" + bookid + "'";
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, con);
SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(query4, con);
con.Open();
string temporaryquantity = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
string temporaryquantitystocks = cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
string totalcostforstocks = (temporaryquantitystocks-temporaryquantity + quantity) * buyingpriceperbook;
```

"quantity" is in int type
"buyingpriceperbook" is in double type

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Seems pretty clear - you can't "subtract" two strings ,even iof those strings represent numeric values. You have to convert them to numeric types first.

Comment: You can't add two strings together... You get a scalar out of your execute operation then immediately `ToString` it... You are trying to sum strings.

Comment: @Charleh You _can_ "add" two strings (meaning you can use the `+` operator), but that _concatenates_ them.

Comment: Yeah true, you knew what I meant though (mathematically)! Using operator+ here is not going to give you the results you want :(

Comment: _"quantity" is an int type_

Comment: Thanks everybody for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not apply arithmetic operators to strings.  Change to double or integer:

```
string query3 = "SELECT Quantity FROM Supplier WHERE [Supplier ID]='" + supplierid + "'";
string query4 = "SELECT Quantity FROM Supplier WHERE [Book ID] = '" + bookid + "'";

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, con);
SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(query4, con);
con.Open();
double temporaryquantity = Convert.ToDouble( cmd3.ExecuteScalar());
double temporaryquantitystocks = Convert.ToDouble(cmd4.ExecuteScalar());
double totalcostforstocks = (temporaryquantitystocks - temporaryquantity + quantity) * buyingpriceperbook;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a numeric type rather than strings:

```
int temporaryquantity = (int)cmd3.ExecuteScalar();
```

Other things to note:

- `ExecuteScalar` will give you only the *first* value from your query - are your queries guaranteed to only return one value? Or are you expecting something to sum up multiple values?
- `ExecuteScalar` returns an `object`, meaning it can be a string, a double, an integer, null, etc. If you cast to `int` you are *assuming* that the query is returning a non-null integer value, otherwise it will fail at runtime.

Comment: Also, he may need to check for null.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works perfectly fine. Thanks for explaining this to me.